# Python terminal gives error after opening

Tags: python, terminal

When I was trying to open python from terminal via `python` command, I faced with an error out of nowhere, terminal works as normal but I want to learn why this happened, thanks in advance.

```
PS C:\Users\blackbird> py
AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\blackbird\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site.py", line 440, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "C:\Users\blackbird\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 165, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "C:\Users\blackbird\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "C:\Users\blackbird\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1254.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position 886: character maps to <undefined>
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that the `pyreadline` package was unintentionally installed on my computer from a 'requirements.txt' file.

From [documentation](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/tree/master/doc):

> The `pyreadline` package is a python implementation of GNU readline
> functionality it is based on the ctypes based UNC readline package by
> Gary Bishop. It is not complete. It has been tested for use with
> windows 2000 and windows xp.
> ...
> Version 2.1 of `pyreadline` has been verfied for Python 2.7, and 3.4, 3.5.

Removing `pyreadline` package solves the problem.

Comment: For anyone who wants to have the functionality provided by the `pyreadline` package, there is a newer package [`pyreadline3`](https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline3/) that works with newer versions of Python 3.x.