# Getting weird error on running python in cmd then continue normally

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

When I run python on cmd I get this weird error:

```py
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site.py", line 446, in register_readline
    import readline
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\readline.py", line 34, in <module>
    rl = Readline()
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 422, in __init__
    BaseReadline.__init__(self)
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 62, in __init__
    mode.init_editing_mode(None)
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\emacs.py", line 633, in init_editing_mode
    self._bind_key('space',       self.self_insert)
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\modes\basemode.py", line 162, in _bind_key
    if not callable(func):
  File "C:\Users\Khaled\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\py3k_compat.py", line 8, in callable
    return isinstance(x, collections.Callable)
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Callable'
```

But then I continue using python normally:

```py
>>>
```

I did not find any effects of this problem python is running normally but I do not want it to appear and to know what does it do.

Comment: What is `collections.Callable`? I don't think we have Callable in collections module

Comment: This looks like a version mismatch to me.

Comment: Your copy of `pyreadline` seems to be from a Python version earlier than 3.9, which is the point at which `collections.Callable` was removed in favor of `collections.abc.Callable`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python terminal gives error after opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798700/python-terminal-gives-error-after-opening)